# What is HuaweiOnlineUpdataService?

Tags: services, huawei-u8150

I have just seen this line in logcat:

```
I/ActivityManager(  235): Start proc com.huawei.updata for service com.huawei.updata/.service.HuaweiOnlineUpdataService: pid=24608 uid=10048 gids={2001, 3003}
```

on a HUAWEI U8150 IDEOS with Android 2.2.

Any idea what is the goal of this `HuaweiOnlineUpdataService`?
Google has only 5 results for this term, with not enough information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this service will running in background to show any updates is available for your phone.